# How can I use contains to look for keyword including a space?

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

I want to use `contains` with search a word that has single space on left and right side. But it is not working..

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE Contains(name, ' Hertz ');
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I'm not so sure you can use `CONTAINS` to search for ending characters. You can search for prefixes with the wildcard * (`CONTAINS(name, '" *"Hertz')`). You might need to add an additional clause to validate that the last char is a space.

Comment: To all the people answering, the OP is asking for `CONTAINS` which uses a full text index and behaves different than `LIKE`.

Comment: You can write where condition as - `WHERE a.name like ' %% '` Check my answer.

Comment: @Janna you can try your luck posting on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You Can LTRIM RTRIM the column and can get the values.

```
create table #temp
(
name varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values(' hertz')

insert into #temp values('hertz ')

insert into #temp values('hertzx')

insert into #temp values('hertz')

select * from #temp where LTRIM(RTRIM(name)) like '%hertz%'
```

If you want to search if it has space in start or end use below query.

```
select * from #temp where name like ' %'

select * from #temp where name like '% '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name=' Hertz '
```

If Hertz is just an example, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name like ' % '
```

which will return all the names with an space in the first and last position

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '% Hertz %'
```

[Learn more about like operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name Like '% Hertz %'
```

Answer (score 0):

To search with spaces included, you need to enclose your expression within double quotes, like :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CONTAINS(name, '" Hertz "');
```

Of course this also can be written with LIKE (although it will be less efficient when dealing with large data sets) :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE name LIKE '% Hertz %');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **like** operator, you no need to give spaces between that like below

```
select * from mytable where name like '%her%'
```

And also if you want the data of which having spaces, you can use like below

```
select * from mytable where name like '_%hertz%_'
```

If we use **underscore**, it will skip the particular position element and search the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from mytable where replace(name,' ','')='Hertz'
```

You can also use `ltrim` & `rtrim` to remove spaces at run time to match the name values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM mytable a
   WHERE a.name like ' %% '
```

OR

```
SELECT a.name
      FROM mytable a
       WHERE a.name like' % '
```

You can find the live demo [**Demo here**](https://rextester.com/BECE9953)